# process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK not available on remote server

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I have a node server running on a Digital Ocean vserver.

I need access to the environment variable **process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK**.

It seems to be set but not available to the node context (process.env).

How can I fix this?
Any hint appreciated...

Comment: How do you conclude it's set?

Comment: At some point echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK showed that it was set. But currently it returns nothing... What is the best way to setup SSH Auth Sock so I can use it in node?

Comment: Start `ssh-agent` before Node? Or perhaps parse the output of `ssh-agent -s`? Not sure, never did anything like that :)

Comment: That is exactly what I did. But no success. I am also using pm2. Is it possible that pm2 is causing the trouble (e.g. different process ?!?)?

Comment: If `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` doesn't show anything in the shell before starting your Node app, it's not caused by pm2.

Answer (score 0):

Start `ssh-agent` to set the environment variable `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on your VPS. You should see output like:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ApEANm9BwwMP/agent.9; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=10; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 10;
```

It will become available via `process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in node thereafter.